# Python to GAS translation not working: get bad request error

Tags: python, google-apps-script, post, bad-request

I want the following code to be translated into GAS from python. I wrote the GAS version pasted below but it is not working. It must be something simple but I don't know the reason why I get this error. Any advice will be appreciated. Thanks.

```
import requests

requestId = "*******************"
url = "http://myapi/internal/ocr/"+requestid+"/ng"

payload={}
headers = {
  'X-Authorization': 'abcdefghijklmn'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)

print(response.text)
```

I wrote this at the moment but I get bad request error.

```
function sending(yesorno, requestId) {  
  var requestId = "*******************"
　var STAGING_KEY = "abcdefghijklmn"

  var url = url = "http://myapi/internal/ocr/"+requestId+"/ng"

  var data = {}
  var options = {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': JSON.stringify(data),
    'headers': {
      'X-Authorization': STAGING_KEY
    }
  };

  //Error processing
  try {
    var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options));
    if (response && response["id"]) {
      return 'sent';
    } else {
      //reportError("Invalid response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
      //return 'error';
      Logger.log('error')
    }    
  } catch (e) {
    //reportError(e.toString());
    //return 'error';
    Logger.log('error')
  }  
}
```

> Modified Code

```
function sending() {
  var requestId = "*************************"
  var STAGING_KEY = "abcdefghijklmn"
  var url = "http://myapi/internal/ocr/"+requestId+"/ng";
  var data = {}
  var options = {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': data,
    'headers': {
      'X-Authorization': STAGING_KEY
    }
  };
  try {
    var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText());
    Logger.log(response)
    if (response && response["id"]) {
      return 'sent';
    } else {
      //reportError("Invalid response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
      //return 'error';
      Logger.log('error1')
    }
  } catch (e) {
    //reportError(e.toString());
    //return 'error';
    Logger.log('error2: '+ e.toString())
  }
  }
```

> Error

```
error2: Exception: Bad request:
```

Comment: In your question, you have already confirmed that your python script worked fine. And, you want to convert the python script to Google Apps Script. Is my understanding correct? And, can you provide the detail of `request error`?

Comment: @Tanaike Thanks for the comment. Yes your understanding is correct. And when I run the GAS code below I get `Exception: Bad request:` only. So it's hard to identify the reason...

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direct solution to your issue, I apologize.

Comment: Try `muteHttpExceptions': false` to get any error details.

Comment: Does your API expect the data to be formatted as JSON? Or just url-encoded parameters?

Comment: @TheAddonDepot thanks for your comment. I don't get any response after posting so I have no idea what form is expected actually. And this API was created inhouse and we are not able to ask about its details to the developers for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I understood your situation as follows.

- Your python script works fine.
- You want to convert the python script to Google Apps Script.
- When your Google Apps Script is run, an error `Exception: Bad request:` occurs.

In this case, how about the following modification? When `response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data=payload)` is used with `payload={}`, I think that at Google Apps Script, it's `'payload': {}`.

#### Modified script:

```js
function sending() {
  var requestId = "*******************"
  var STAGING_KEY = "abcdefghijklmn"
  var url = "http://myapi/internal/ocr/" + requestId + "/ng"
  var data = {}
  var options = {
    'muteHttpExceptions': true,
    'method': 'post',
    'payload': data,
    'headers': {
      'X-Authorization': STAGING_KEY
    }
  };
  try {
    var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options).getContentText());
    console.log(response)
    if (response && response["id"]) {
      return 'sent';
    } else {
      //reportError("Invalid response: " + JSON.stringify(response));
      //return 'error';
      Logger.log('error')
    }
  } catch (e) {
    //reportError(e.toString());
    //return 'error';
    Logger.log('error')
  }
}
```

#### Note:

- By the above modification, the request of Google Apps Script is the same as that of the python script. But if an error occurs, please check the URL and your `STAGING_KEY`, again. And, please check whether the API you want to use can access from the Google side.

#### Reference:

- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)

Comment: Thank you so much for your suggestion! I still get the same error though... and the process skips `try` and go go away to `catch`. That means `fetch` itself is failing. If the code is correct, the server could block the access or something...??

Comment: @Aoki SJ Seonok Yang Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About `I still get the same error`, can you provide the detail of it? And when the API you want to use cannot be accessed from Google side, an error might occur. But I'm not sure about the detail of your API. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. At least, my proposed modification is the same request of your python script.

Comment: @Aoki SJ Seonok Yang And also, can you add your current script for replicating your current situation to your question?

Comment: I really appreciate your comments. I updated my question. Thanks.

Comment: @Aoki SJ Seonok Yang Thank you for replying. When I saw your added script, the request of Google Apps Script is the same as your python script. Unfortunately, I cannot know the detailed specification of the API you expect, for example, when you removed `'payload': data,`, what result will you obtain?

Comment: Thank you! I tried again without `'payload': data` but nothing changed... python and curl works with the same api so I guess the UserAgent is blocked by the server or something...

Comment: @Aoki SJ Seonok Yang Thank you for replying. As I have already mentioned in my answer, when your API cannot be accessed from Google side, an error might occur. So how about confirming this? By the way, unfortunately, in the current stage, Google Apps Script cannot change the user-agent. I apologize for this. For example, how about running the request on a dialog of Google Docs? By this, you can request with Javascript of your own browser. I thought that by this, the situation might be changed. But if this was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanations. I guess it's because of UserAgent which is fixed and not editable when you post via GAS. Thank you so much for your help anyways!

Comment: @Aoki SJ Seonok Yang Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that your issue couldn't be resolved by the current specification on the Google side.